# WildCard ArrayList<?>

Tags: java, arraylist

Почему если я создаю `ArrayList<?>`, то не могу в него ничего добавить? Насколько я понял, то **?** означает любой тип-наследник `Object`. Ведь `String` же является наследником от `Object`, тогда почему я не могу его добавить в такой список?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList<?>` эквивалентно `ArrayList<? extends Object>`, а далее используются следующие правила.

**Ковариантность**

Ковариантность позволяет читать элементы из структуры данных, но не писать в неё. Например, эти декларации верны:

```
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Float>();
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Мы можем прочитать значение:

```
Number n = myNums.get(0);
```

Мы можем это сделать, потому что уверены, что чтобы ни было в листе, оно будет являться дочерним типом `Number`.

Однако, мы не можем туда писать, так как Java не гарантирует тип в нашей структуре данных (в данном случае это может быть Integer, или Float, или Double):

```
myNumst.add(45L); //compiler error
```

**Контравариантность**

С контравариантностью все наоборот. Мы можем писать, но не может читать из структуры данных.

```
List<Object> myObjs = new List<Object>();
myObjs.add("Luke");
myObjs.add("Obi-wan");

List<? super Number> myNums = myObjs;
myNums.add(10);
myNums.add(3.14);
```

В этом случае, мы можем записать значения, так как все числа имеют тип `Object` как их общего предка.

Однако безопасно читать мы не можем, потому что нет гарантий, что в структуре лежит объект типа `Number`:

```
Number myNum = myNums.get(0); //compiler error
```

Answer (score 3):

тут `?` значит то что тип данных неизвестен, и является супертипом класса Collection. И даже не является классом `Object`

Вот давай подумаем) Если **?** являлся бы объектом, тогда почему `Collection<Object>` не является супертипом, а вместо этого `Collection<?>`?

Рассмотрим внизу пример:

```
Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add(new Object()); //Компилятор выдаст ошибку
```

Так как мы не знаем тип элемента `c`, и не можем добавлять объекты в него. И вообще в коллекциях метод `.add()` принимает аргументы типа `E`, то есть тип элемента коллекции.. То есть с помощью метода .add() ты не сможешь это реализовать... Касается всех наследников класса Collection, в том числе и наш ArrayList<>

[Вот про wildcars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) с официальной документации

[Вот на русском](https://habrahabr.ru/post/207360/)

[И вот еще](https://www.google.az/webhp?q=wildcard%20in%20java)